# error: Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'

Tags: javascript, html, validation, ecmascript-6, eslint

In my eslint validation when I am trying to pass the eslint check I am getting this error: Expected an identifier and instead saw '<'. This is causing in my line 1 and 2 also. My code is given below, please can anyone help me,

```
<body>
<script>
let callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    let [added] = mutation.addedNodes;
    if (added instanceof HTMLIFrameElement && added.id == "firefox-screenshots-preview-iframe") {
      added.srcdoc = "<html></html>";
      // Now we have to wait for the doc to be populated.
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        console.log(added.contentDocument.innerHTML);
        if (added.contentDocument.body.innerHTML) {
          clearInterval(interval);
          window.responseHandler(added.contentDocument.body.innerHTML);
        }
      }, 100);
      observer.disconnect();
    }
  }
};

observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(document.body, {childList: true});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: eslint is for javascript, this is an HTML page (containing js). What if you isolate the contents of that `<script>` block and test just *that*?

Comment: But how can I isolate can you show me an example @HansKeﬆing

Comment: Just copy that js code into a new file and check only that. You could then update that script element: remove the js code and add a "src" attribute to point to that file (`<script src="my_script_file.js"></script>`)

Comment: I had done that but still causing same error

Comment: Your code is just fine - i tested it in my test file. I think the error is before the opening body tag or in a flie you implemented (maybe css). The error should say which file and which line - give us this info...